# Creating a DLL that can be used by native and managed applications

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli, native, managed

Even after searching a while I could not find a clear answer to this. It seems to be somewhat of an uncommon problem:

I have a native implementation that should go in a DLL. That DLL should be usable by both native applications as well as managed applications.

So if I write this DLL in C++/CLI I could expose two things:

1. A flat, C-style exported interface of functions that could be used by native applications.
2. A Managed class that can be used from any managed application (e.g. C#) by referencing this DLL

Will this work? Will purely native applications be able to load this DLL and call the exposed functions?

Comment: Yes, this is one of the reasons why C++/CLI exists - it's not at all "uncommon", we do it all the time. [MSDN is very clear on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx)

Comment: COM components can be called from native and managed code; that's another alternative.

Comment: As it turns out this seems not to work. I have to compile my DLL with /MT switch (maybe because of one of the Libs I'm linking?). But then I can't compile with /clr (/MT and /clr don't work together, says the linker)... Argh!

Comment: Use simple layering techniques.  Write the native code first so it is directly usable from unmanaged code.  Add a C++/CLI layer on top of it, that uses the native code, so it is usable from managed code.  Using pure managed code from native code is possible, just a lot harder to get right.  You have to understand COM.

Answer (score 0):

The native DLL is compiled like a regular native DLL (no /clr).
The calling C++/CLI application/DLL uses a C++ class to load the DLL via LoadLibrary and GetProcAdress.
You need to have the above C++ class map all the functions of the native DLL.
The C++ class acts as a proxy class:

Example:

Native DLL hasa function `foo()`.

C++/CLI code exposes a method foo which looks like:

```
void MyProxy::foo() {
    m_foo(); // m_foo is a function pointer to foo() in the DLL obtained via GetProcAddress.
}
```